# How do I get a Synergy Crystal and what does it do?

Tags: rift

The title says it all. I have come across a piece of armor that needs a synergy crystal for it's set bonus. I was unable to find one though.

[image: Picture of Armor Piece]

What does a Synergy Crystal do and how do I get one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used to activate the set bonus of Transplanar gear. They are sold by main city Faction Vendors.

Comment: And where would I find those? A bit more effort please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In Meridian they are the planar vendor npcs through the western (to your left) arch of the manufactory.  I just bought one and don't have the armor for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For Guardians, you can buy them from Quartermaster Nysmen in the Sanctum of the Vigil, at (7469,3008) in Sanctum. They're all level 50+, though. If I find any lower-level ones, I'll update.